# Need to exec $SHELL on new terminal for settings to work

Tags: command-line, bash, bashrc

Unsure what is interfering with my shell, on every new shell I need to exec $SHELL to get correct settings to take.

I am getting this prompt by default

```
sayth@sayth-TravelMate-5740G:~$
```

and after exec $SHELL and its working

```
sayth@sayth-TravelMate-5740G:~$ exec $SHELL
sayth:~$
```

This is my .bashrc

```
# ~/.bashrc: executed by bash(1) for non-login shells.
# see /usr/share/doc/bash/examples/startup-files (in the package bash-doc)
# for examples

# If not running interactively, don't do anything
case $- in
    *i*) ;;
      *) return;;
esac

# don't put duplicate lines or lines starting with space in the history.
# See bash(1) for more options
HISTCONTROL=ignoreboth

# append to the history file, don't overwrite it
shopt -s histappend

# for setting history length see HISTSIZE and HISTFILESIZE in bash(1)
HISTSIZE=1000
HISTFILESIZE=2000

# check the window size after each command and, if necessary,
# update the values of LINES and COLUMNS.
shopt -s checkwinsize

# If set, the pattern "**" used in a pathname expansion context will
# match all files and zero or more directories and subdirectories.
#shopt -s globstar

# make less more friendly for non-text input files, see lesspipe(1)
[ -x /usr/bin/lesspipe ] && eval "$(SHELL=/bin/sh lesspipe)"

# set variable identifying the chroot you work in (used in the prompt below)
if [ -z "${debian_chroot:-}" ] && [ -r /etc/debian_chroot ]; then
    debian_chroot=$(cat /etc/debian_chroot)
fi

# set a fancy prompt (non-color, unless we know we "want" color)
case "$TERM" in
    xterm-color) color_prompt=yes;;
esac

# uncomment for a colored prompt, if the terminal has the capability; turned
# off by default to not distract the user: the focus in a terminal window
# should be on the output of commands, not on the prompt
force_color_prompt=yes

if [ -n "$force_color_prompt" ]; then
    if [ -x /usr/bin/tput ] && tput setaf 1 >&/dev/null; then
    # We have color support; assume it's compliant with Ecma-48
    # (ISO/IEC-6429). (Lack of such support is extremely rare, and such
    # a case would tend to support setf rather than setaf.)
    color_prompt=yes
    else
    color_prompt=
    fi
fi

if [ "$color_prompt" = yes ]; then
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\$ '
else
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u:\W\$ '
fi
unset color_prompt force_color_prompt

# If this is an xterm set the title to user@host:dir
case "$TERM" in
xterm*|rxvt*)
    PS1="\[\e]0;${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h: \w\a\]$PS1"
    ;;
*)
    ;;
esac

# enable color support of ls and also add handy aliases
if [ -x /usr/bin/dircolors ]; then
    test -r ~/.dircolors && eval "$(dircolors -b ~/.dircolors)" || eval "$(dircolors -b)"
    alias ls='ls --color=auto'
    #alias dir='dir --color=auto'
    #alias vdir='vdir --color=auto'

    alias grep='grep --color=auto'
    alias fgrep='fgrep --color=auto'
    alias egrep='egrep --color=auto'
fi

# some more ls aliases
alias ll='ls -alF'
alias la='ls -A'
alias l='ls -CF'

# Add an "alert" alias for long running commands.  Use like so:
#   sleep 10; alert
alias alert='notify-send --urgency=low -i "$([ $? = 0 ] && echo terminal || echo error)" "$(history|tail -n1|sed -e '\''s/^\s*[0-9]\+\s*//;s/[;&|]\s*alert$//'\'')"'

# Alias definitions.
# You may want to put all your additions into a separate file like
# ~/.bash_aliases, instead of adding them here directly.
# See /usr/share/doc/bash-doc/examples in the bash-doc package.

if [ -f ~/.bash_aliases ]; then
    . ~/.bash_aliases
fi

# enable programmable completion features (you don't need to enable
# this, if it's already enabled in /etc/bash.bashrc and /etc/profile
# sources /etc/bash.bashrc).
if ! shopt -oq posix; then
  if [ -f /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion ]; then
    . /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion
  elif [ -f /etc/bash_completion ]; then
    . /etc/bash_completion
  fi
fi

# pip bash completion start
_pip_completion()
{
    COMPREPLY=( $( COMP_WORDS="${COMP_WORDS[*]}" \
                   COMP_CWORD=$COMP_CWORD \
                   PIP_AUTO_COMPLETE=1 $1 ) )
}
complete -o default -F _pip_completion pip
# pip bash completion end
```

The pip completion section I have commented out and restarted shell and it had no effect the same with my bash_profile I have commented out and it had no effect.

bash_profile

```
export PATH="$HOME/.pyenv/bin:$PATH"
eval "$(pyenv init -)"
eval "$(pyenv virtualenv-init -)"
```

Comment: Does `source ~/.bashrc` also fix the problem?

Comment: @Sparhawk      Yes it does

Comment: can you try commenting out the lines after `# If this is an xterm set the title to user@host:dir` to the next comment?

Comment: The other thing I can think of is that for some reason `~/.bashrc` is correctly being sourced in a new terminal, but for some reason, something else is overwriting `PS1`. Can you test that `~/.bashrc` is being executed, by putting something like `echo Ahaaaa` in it?

Comment: @Sparhawk      Its not being sourced at all the echo Ahaaaa doesn't work unless you source the file. this is while having the xterm section commented out.

Comment: ok figured it added this to my bash_profile and all is working [[ -f ~/.bashrc ]] && source ~/.bashrc

Comment: I'm glad you worked it out! Please make the solution an answer below, then accept it. Cheers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Resolved using section from this answer [Ubuntu - .bashrc not loaded, .bash_profile exists](https://serverfault.com/a/496513)

Resolution

```
[[ -f ~/.bashrc ]] && source ~/.bashrc
```